# Complexity and Big-O Notation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

What is the worst case time complexity for the following two algorithms assuming items (an `ArrayList<Integer>`)has enough unused space that it never needs to be re-sized? My initial guess is that A would run slower because it has to shift every element over to add the new one at index `[0]`. I think B is `O(N^2)` in the worst case but I am not sure.

A.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    items.add(0, new Integer(i));
```

and B.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    items.add(new Integer(i));
```

Comment: Please be more specific: What language is this ? Is ArrayList implementation standardized in that language ? If no, no one will give you general answer. If yes - read the standard.

Comment: its written in java and it is standardized.

Comment: My comment below assumes Java, since the term ArrayList is used and becaause the add method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about java, then first version is slower and has complexity `O(N^2)`for the very reason you  mention, while B has complexity `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation A could be, by assuming that the `items` array is sufficiently large, implemented as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = items.size; j > 0; j++) {
        items[j] = items[j-1]; 
    }
    items[0] = i;
}
```

The total number of operations executed in this case (assuming `m` was the initial size of the `items` list) would be:

[image]

This has the complexity **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Option B, on the other hand, can be implemented as

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    items[items.size] = i;
    items.size++;
}
```

and the number of operations executed in this case will be

[image]

This has the complexity **O(n)**

Comment: Oops! Not sure why my MathJax is not rendering properly!

Answer (score 0):

in A, you must shift all of the items to the right one in the internal array of the array list for each insertion.  This will be O(n^2) to complete the operation. In the second case, no shifting is needed so it will be O(n).  In A, you are doing tons of unnecessary and expensive work.

I am assuming, as you had stipulated, that the internal array is not resized.